# $\varphi : \mathbb{C}^*\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^*$ is defined by $\varphi(x+iy)=x^2+y^2$,what is the kernel of $\varphi$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm not sure what the kernel is here (I have not taken complex analysis yet). I understand that the kernel is $\ker\varphi=\lbrace z\in \mathbb{C}^* \mid \varphi(z)=1 \rbrace$, where $z=x+iy$. Do I have to use $\varphi=x^2+y^2$? How would I begin finding the kernel? I originally thought that it would be $\ker\varphi=\lbrace \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \rbrace$, because it would make $x^2+y^2=1$ and $\lbrace \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \rbrace \in \mathbb{C}^*$. I am lead that I should have more elements. What am I missing?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're on the right track.  You need to find $z$'s so that $\varphi(z)=x^2+y^2=1$.  Can you think of which points satisfy $x^2+y^2=1$?

Comment: You're also missing, for example, the points $\pm 1$ and $\pm i$, not to mention $\pm \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$.

Comment: @TheoBendit so I should have 10 elements (yours and mine)? How did you solve for $\pm \frac{1}{2}\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$? did you find it through solving zv=(x+iy)(a+ib), using the product of two complex numbers?

Comment: What is this kernel for? In linear algebra (finite or infinite dimensional), kernel refers to the pre-image of 0 of a linear operator.

Comment: Why was this question asked twice?

Comment: @AsafKaragila this was part of my other question that I still had trouble figuring it out. I wasn't sure whether or not I was going to get the answer I wanted so I posted this to tackle this part specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel is the preimage of the identity so every complex number with $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is the kernel of this transformation. To understand what the kernel consists of it helps to represent the complex numbers in polar form as $re^{2 \pi i \theta}$ with $r$ the radius and since $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$ and we see that the kernel is the unit circle in the punctured complex plane.

Comment: Thanks. I will into this.